# Having an MDI Form inside another MDI Form in C#

Tags: c#, mdichild, mdiparent

I’m working on a c# project that has an MDI Form as the main form with some other Forms as its Child Forms.
Now I’m thinking of having another MDI Form inside the first one as child. But C# says that a Form can be either MDI Child or MDI Parent.
Is there any way to open an MDI Form inside the other MDI Form as its child?

Comment: That's not an MDI form then. MDI means Multiple *Document* Interface,. Child forms aren't just child forms, they represent a *single document*. Are you trying to use an MDI form to do something different perhaps?

Comment: Not using MDI, no.  But you can embed forms within other forms by setting `TopLevel` to false.  Then you can add the "child" form to a Panel, TabControl, etc...